# Wipe a USB flash drive and recreate a filesystem

Tags: hard-disk, dd, fdisk, mkfs, disk-cleanup

I'm using this to wipe a USB flash drive and recreate a FAT filesystem:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M    #I don't need more advanced wiping
fdisk /dev/sdb
(a few keystrokes to select partition type, etc.)
mkfs.fat /dev/sdb1
```

The fact that I have to manually do a few keystrokes is annoying. How could I do all of this in one step, without any intervention? Something like:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M && ??? &&& mkfs.fat /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here-document syntax allows you to use `fdisk` non-interactively:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb <<EOF
n
p



t
b
p
q
EOF
```

Because this is just an example, I used `p` and `q` so no changes are written. Use `w` after your verified sequence.

Note a blank line corresponds to sole <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The point is you can pass your keystrokes this way.

Alternatively you can write those lines (between two `EOF`-s) to a file, say `fdisk.commands`, and then:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb < fdisk.commands
```

Or without a file (from a comment, thank you Rastapopoulos):

```
fdisk /dev/sdb <<< $'n\np\n\n\n\nt\nb\np\nq'
```

Another way:

```
printf '%s\n' "n" "p" "" "" "" "t" "b" "p" "q" | fdisk /dev/sdb
```

---

There's also [`sfdisk`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sfdisk). You may find its syntax more suitable for you.

Comment: OK, this was a mistake.

Comment: Check my updated answer. You shouldn't expect you can do all of this in strictly one command. Unix philosophy says one tool should do one thing. You're doing three things.

Comment: You can use `<<<`: `fdisk /dev/sdb <<< $'n\np\n\n\n\nt\nb\np\n'`, no?

Comment: @Rastapopoulos You're right. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @KamilMaciorowski's answer (full credit to him), here is what I finally use:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=1M && sudo fdisk /dev/sdb <<< $'n\np\n\n\n\nt\nb\np\nw\n' && sudo mkfs.fat /dev/sdb1
```